# Prove the number of total dominating sets of a bipartite graph is not exactly divisible by $2$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

here is a cute problem I created from another not so cute problem I made from a cute problem. Prove the number of total dominating sets of a bipartite graph is never exactly divisible by $2$ ( of the form $2k$ with $k$ odd).

A total dominating set is a set of vertices such that all vertices in the graph (including the vertices in the dominating set themselves) have a neighbor in the dominating set.

Regards.

Comment: The last problem I posted was similar to this one because I made a mistake on the last one and it didn't have the solution I was hoping for(although it also happened to be true by mere coincidence). This problem does have a very neat solution.

Comment: Any reason it isn't stated as "number of dominating sets is odd"?

Comment: the number of "total" dominating sets can be even

Comment: If the number of "total" dominating sets can be even, why are you asking us to prove that it can't be even? What am I missing?

Comment: It must be that by "exactly divisible by 2" is meant $2u$ with $u$ odd, is that right? (Found one with 4 dominating sets...)

Comment: yes, I meant that.

Comment: If you meant that, why didn't you just **say** that? If only people would say what they mean . . .

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was common use that when someone says exactly divisible by a prime it means divisible by that prime but no other positive integer power of the prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We call a set of vertices in one of the parts of the bipartite graph a dominator if every vertex in the other part of the graph is a neighbour of at least one of the vertices in the dominator.

Therefore a set of a bipartite graph with parts $A$ and $B$ is a totally dominating set if and only if the set of its vertices that are  in $A$ is a dominator set and the set of vertices in $B$ is a dominator set. therefore the number of totally dominating sets of a bipartite graph with parts $A$ and $B$ is equal to the product of the number of dominator sets of vertices in $A$ multiplied by the number of dominator sets of vertices in $B$.

We shall prove that these last two numbers have the same parity, which proves this number must be odd or a product of two even numbers (hence not exactly divisible by $2$). To prove this consider all of the pairs of sets of vertices $A'\subseteq A$ and $B'\subseteq B$  such that there are no edges between $A'$ and $B'$.

Given a specific subset $A'$ how many such pairs $A',B'$ are there? consider the set of vertices in $B$ not in the neighbourhood of $A$. Then we have $B'$ must be any subset of the set of these vertices, hence the number of pairs $A'B'$ where $A'$ is fixed is odd if and only if $A'$ is a dominator set. Hence the parity of the number of pairs $A',B'$ is equal to the number of dominator sets $A'$. Using the exact same argument fixing a given $B'$ it is also equal to the the number of dominator sets $B'$